# Event Listener for CSS in AngularJS directive not being fired / caught

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I'm trying to perform an action after a css animation has finished. The directive looks like so....

```
.directive('catchProfileAnimation', function ( ) {
    'use strict';

    /* I stole this from Modernizr */
    function whichTransitionEvent() {
        var t;
        var el = document.createElement('fakeelement');
        var transitions = {
            'transition': 'transitionend',
            'OTransition': 'oTransitionEnd',
            'MozTransition': 'transitionend',
            'WebkitTransition': 'webkitTransitionEnd'
        };

        for (t in transitions) {
            if (el.style[t] !== undefined) {
                return transitions[t];
            }
        }
    }
    /* Get event Type */
    var transitionEvent = whichTransitionEvent();


    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element) {

            element.bind(transitionEvent, function (evt) {
                console.log('animation complete!', evt);
            });

        }
    }
});
```

within my HTML it looks like so...

```
<div data-ng-show="profile.showProfile" class="profile-card" data-ng-class="{'slide-left-slow': profile.showProfile }" data-catch-profile-animation>
Lot's of lovely HTML here
</div>
```

the css class looks like so...

```
.slide-left-slow {

    background-color: $white;
    -webkit-animation: slide-l-100 .4s ease-in !important;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1 !important;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards !important;
    -webkit-transform:translate(-100%);

    -moz-animation: slide-l-100 .4s ease-in !important;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1 !important;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards !important;
    -moz-transform:translate(-100%);

    animation: slide-l-100 .4s ease-in !important;
    animation-iteration-count: 1 !important;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards !important;
    transform:translate(-100%);
}

@keyframes slide-l-100 {
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(0%);
        -moz-transform: translate(0%);
        transform: translate(0%);
    }
}
```

Once the CTRL sets the value of `profile.showProfile` the animation is performed and when I inspect the element in the Chrome Dev Tools the element has the EventListener registered. However the message `console.log('animation complete!', evt);` is not being sent to the console. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code triggers `animationEnd` event instead of `transitionEnd`. I tried replacing your transitions array with the code below and tested on my chrome browser:

```
var transitions = {
            'WebkitAnimation': 'webkitAnimationEnd'
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the answer above I realised my error, I changed the `function whichTransitionEvent()` to listen for `animationend` not `transitionend`! The points go to Merhawi, but I thought I'd include my answer...

```
function whichAnimationEvent() {
            var t;
            var el = document.createElement('fakeelement');
            var animation = {
                "animation"      : "animationend",
                "OAnimation"     : "oAnimationEnd",
                "MozAnimation"   : "animationend",
                "WebkitAnimation": "webkitAnimationEnd"
            };

            for (t in animation) {
                if (el.style[t] !== undefined) {
                    return animation[t];
                }
            }
        }
        /* Get event Type */
        var animationEvent = whichAnimationEvent();

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element) {
            element.bind(animationEvent, function (evt) {
                console.log('animation complete!', evt);
            });

        }
    }
```